# ActiveMerchant Authorize.net Cim wont generate declines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorize.net, activemerchant

I'm working on an implementation with ActiveMerchant that uses AuthorizeNetCim.

I followed this [guide](http://www.authorize.net/files/ErrorGenerationGuide.pdf) to generate a declined transaction or AVS errors.

Every transaction I do, will return as a successful transaction.

I'm setting the ActiveMerchant flag to true so that it hits the test_url.

This is the only thread I've found in regards the same [problem](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/CIM-Using-test-mode-to-generate-specific-transaction-results-not/m-p/35033).

Answer (score 1):

This pull request solves the problem:

https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/pull/785

Basically we need to split the test flag in two:
- test : Indicates which url to hit.
- test_requests : Indicates if requests should carry the test flag or not.

This way, you can hit the test environment but send a *real* transaction which will react to the error generation guide from authorize.net.

Comment: You were able to get declined results back?  I am sending Zip codes from this URL and getting successes back.  http://developer.authorize.net/tools/errorgenerationguide/

Comment: Yes. It's important to set your account as not sandbox env. I opened a test account with Authorize.net and that account is in "live" environment, not sandboxed. Also, make sure to set up the `test_requests` flag correctly.